# Reduce amount of queries and increase performance for categories and subcategories queries

Tags: php, mysql

EDIT 3: Got it down to 300-500 ms by changing flatten method to only merge arrays if not empty.

EDIT 2: Got it down to 1.6 seconds by only calling `array_replace` for non empty array. Now all that is left to do is optimize the function `sort_categories_and_sub_categories`. That is NOW the bottleneck. If I remove that I am down to 300ms. Any ideas?

`get_all_categories_and_sub_categories`

```
foreach(array_keys($categories) as $id)
{

    $subcategories = $this->get_all_categories_and_sub_categories($id, $depth + 1);

    if (!empty($subcategories))
    {
        $categories = array_replace($categories, $subcategories);
    }
}
```

EDIT

I improved performance by over 50% (6 seconds --> 2.5 seconds) by doing a cache in the get_all method. It reduces the amount of queries to 1 from 3000. I am still wondering why it is slow.

I have the following method for getting categories and nested sub categories. If a user has a couple hundred (or thousand) top level categories it does a bunch of queries for each category to find the children. In one case I have 3000 categories and it did 3000 queries. Is there a way to optimize this to do less queries? OR should I just check to see if they have a lot of categories NOT to try to show nested too.

```
function get_all_categories_and_sub_categories($parent_id = NULL, $depth = 0)
{
    $categories = $this->get_all($parent_id);
    if (!empty($categories))
    {
        foreach($categories as $id => $value)
        {
            $categories[$id]['depth'] = $depth;
        }

        foreach(array_keys($categories) as $id)
        {
            $categories = array_replace($categories, $this->get_all_categories_and_sub_categories($id, $depth + 1));
        }

        return $categories;
    }
    else
    {           
        return $categories;
    }
}


function get_all($parent_id = NULL, $limit=10000, $offset=0,$col='name',$order='asc')
{
    static $cache = array();

    if (!$cache)
    {
        $this->db->from('categories');
        $this->db->where('deleted',0);
        if (!$this->config->item('speed_up_search_queries'))
        {
            $this->db->order_by($col, $order);
        }

        $this->db->limit($limit);
        $this->db->offset($offset);

        foreach($this->db->get()->result_array() as $result)
        {
            $cache[$result['parent_id'] ? $result['parent_id'] : 0][] = array('name' => $result['name'], 'parent_id' => $result['parent_id'], 'id' => $result['id']);
        }
    }

    $return = array();

    $key = $parent_id == NULL ? 0 : $parent_id;
    if (isset($cache[$key]))
    {   
        foreach($cache[$key] as $row)
        {
            $return[$row['id']] = array('name' => $row['name'], 'parent_id' => $row['parent_id']);
        }
        return $return;
    }

    return $return;

}


function sort_categories_and_sub_categories($categories)
{
    $objects = array();
    // turn to array of objects to make sure our elements are passed by reference
    foreach ($categories as $k => $v) 
    {
        $node = new StdClass();
        $node->id = $k;
        $node->parent_id = $v['parent_id'];
        $node->name = $v['name'];
        $node->depth = $v['depth'];
        $node->children = array();
        $objects[$k] = $node;
    }


    // list dependencies parent -> children
    foreach ($objects as $node)
    {
        $parent_id = $node->parent_id;
        if ($parent_id !== null)
        {
            $objects[$parent_id]->children[] = $node;
        }
    }

    // clean the object list to make kind of a tree (we keep only root elements)
    $sorted = array_filter($objects, array('Category','_filter_to_root'));

    // flatten recursively
    $categories = self::_flatten($sorted);

    $return = array();

    foreach($categories as $category)
    {
        $return[$category->id] = array('depth' => $category->depth, 'name' => $category->name, 'parent_id' => $category->parent_id);
    }

    return $return;
}   

static function _filter_to_root($node)
{
    return $node->depth === 0;
}

static function _flatten($elements) 
{
    $result = array();

    foreach ($elements as $element) 
     {
        if (property_exists($element, 'children')) 
          {
            $children = $element->children;
            unset($element->children);
        } 
          else 
          {
            $children = null;
        }

        $result[] = $element;

        if (isset($children)) 
          {
                $flatened = self::_flatten($children);

                if (!empty($flatened))
                {                 
                    $result = array_merge($result, $flatened);
                } 
          }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: It looks like you may be querying some categories multiple time (except if your categories have a tree structure). Adding a check in your second `foreach` loop like `if (!isset($categories['id'])) {  $categories = ... ; }` could reduce the number of duplicate queries.

Comment: @Holt I have reduced the number of queries from 3000 -->1; but it seems it is still a bit slow.

Comment: Have you set relevant indexes on the table so any `where` clauses will use the indexes rather than general columns?  And does the query you are running use only indexed columns in the query?  This might seem obvious, but it gets overlooked.

Comment: I did it! See code above